# Why is there a left shift in the Risc V processor?

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv

[image]
I can't figure out the purpose of this left shift

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. At the first sight, it seems that the purpose is to multiply the immediate data by 2. The reason might be that jumps to a different address are always to an even (relative) address, but they are stored without the least significant bit so before the addition to the Program Counter (PC) register, the actual value needs to be multiplied by 2 (i.e. shifted by 1 bit). If you edit your question and add some more information - like from where you took this picture, we can see if it there is some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

By shifting (mulitplying by 2) we can address more program memory. And since the program counter value needs to be muliple of 4, the least significant bit is uselless. The reason for dumping just one bit instead of two, is that (and this is only my thought) in RISC-V there exists an 16-bit compressed version of instruction set, so if we need to, we could address those.

Comment: Why the LSB is useless btw? Do they again left shit 1-bit later to eventually generate the target jump address? Because you need to multiply by 4 to get the actual branch target address!